# php mcrypt_decrypt, base64_decode and line break

Tags: mcrypt

How to make a line break? For example:
line1
line2
line3
after decoding, look like -> line1 line2 line3

```
$key =  $_POST['key']; $input = $_POST['text'];

$algo = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($algo, $mode);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

switch($_POST['do']){
    default: die;

    case 'encode':
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt($algo, $key, $input, $mode, $iv);
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
    echo base64_encode($ciphertext);
    break;

    case 'decode':
    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($input);
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);
    echo htmlspecialchars(mcrypt_decrypt($algo, $key, $ciphertext_dec, $mode, $iv_dec));
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I use nl2br

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(mcrypt_decrypt($algo, $key, $ciphertext_dec, $mode, $iv_dec)));
```